# perl subroutine argument lists - "pass by alias"?

Tags: perl, parameters, arguments, pass-by-reference, subroutine

I just looked in disbelief at this sequence:

```
my $line;
$rc = getline($line); # read next line and store in $line
```

I had understood all along that Perl arguments were passed by value, so whenever I've needed to pass in a large structure, or pass in a variable to be updated, I've passed a ref.

Reading the fine print in perldoc, however, I've learned that @_ is composed of *aliases* to the variables mentioned in the argument list.  After reading the next bit of data, **getline()** returns it with **$_[0] = $data;**, which stores **$data** directly into **$line**.

I do like this - it's like passing by reference in C++.  However, I haven't found a way to assign a more meaningful name to **$_[0]**.  Is there any?

Comment: yup, Perl is always pass-by-reference

Comment: Well - not to be confused with Perl references, which are more like C pointers in that they have to be explicitly dereferenced.

Comment: Wouldn't 
  $arg = shift;
  $arg = $data;
do it? Or will 'shift' make a copy of the argument instead?

EDIT: I tested the addresses of a passed scalar and the 'shift'ed argument, and the results say shift does make a copy, so assigning to $arg as above won't affect $line as intended. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, its not very pretty:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub inc {
  # manipulate the local symbol table 
  # to refer to the alias by $name
  our $name; local *name = \$_[0];

  # $name is an alias to first argument
  $name++;
}

my $x = 1;
inc($x);
print $x; # 2
```

Comment: Considerable prettification is available out of `Data::Alias`.

Comment: also, Method::Signatures has an [alias trait](https://metacpan.org/module/Method::Signatures#Parameter-traits)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably just to use a loop, since loops alias their arguments to a name; i.e.

```
sub my_sub {
  for my $arg ( $_[0] ) {
    code here sees $arg as an alias for $_[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: True but not really what I was after -- would ideally have liked to give distinct names to each arg.  Looks like Joel's does that, but as he says, it's pretty messy.

Comment: @Chap: I've added an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17343595/8127 that allows for distinct names for each arg, but that too is messy in its own way.

Answer (score 0):

A version of @Steve's code that allows for multiple distinct arguments:

```
sub my_sub {
  SUB:
  for my $thisarg ( $_[0] ) {
    for my $thatarg ($_[1]) {
      code here sees $thisarg and $thatarg as aliases 
      last SUB;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course this brings multilevel nestings and its own code readability issues, so use it only when absolutely neccessary.